# Reading script and replacing specific line. vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm developing a script that encrypts a users Tacacs-password, and writes this string into another script. My script opens, reads & writes the Tacacs-password into my other script but it doensn't overwrite it.

First run:

strTacacs = "Test1234"

Second run:

strTacacs = "Test1234"strTacacs = "Test1234"

My current script:

```
'***********Write to auto-logon script************

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
newline = "strTacacs = " & chr(34) & Tacacs & chr(34)
line = 30


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim lineCount : lineCount = 0
Dim firstContent : firstContent = ""

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "vbs" Then
        lineCount = 0
        firstContent = ""
        FileName = objStartFolder & objFile.Name
        Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)
        Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
            firstContent = firstContent & objStream.ReadLine & vbCrLf
            'msgbox(firstContent)
            if lineCount = 30 Then 
                firstContent = firstContent & newline
                msgbox(firstContent)
            End if
        Loop  
        Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting)
        objStream.WriteLine firstContent
        objStream.Close 
    End If  
Next
```

.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?
I'm new in the world of scripting so your help is greatly appreciated!

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are writing both the original line and the new line when you get to line 30. You should only write `newline` when `lineCount` is 30 and write the original line otherwise:

```
Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream
    
    lineCount = lineCount + 1
    
    If lineCount = 30 Then
        ' Replace line with newline
        firstContent = firstContent & newline & vbCrLf
    Else
        ' Write original line
        firstContent = firstContent & objStream.ReadLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop
```

If you know the password in the original file, you could read the whole file content in one shot using [ReadAll method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/readall-method):

```
Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)
firstContent = objStream.ReadAll
```

then use [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) to replace the password, and finally write the content back.

You current line-by-line approach is easier if you don't know the password and simply replace a specific line. You could also check if line starts with `strTacacs =` which gets you away from hardcoding the line number:

```
Dim sLine
Dim sPasswordLine
sPasswordLine = "strTacas ="

Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream

    ' Read line
    sLine = objStream.ReadLine

    If Left(sLine, Len(sPasswordLine)) = sPasswordLine Then
        ' Replace line with newline
        firstContent = firstContent & newline & vbCrLf
    Else
        ' Write original line
        firstContent = firstContent & sLine & vbCrLf
    End If
    
Loop
```

Comment: Good explanation.